# Desktop application in Javascript/CSS/HTML for Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have to make a Google Chrome based application solely for desktop purpose. By Desktop I meant that it would not be loaded from some URL rather would be invoked on the machine only. The data would be stored/fetched from HTML5 SQLite databases or some storage provided by CHrome(Is there any?) The application would be purely based on Javascript/CSS/HTML. I also have to make it secure so that nobody could "steal" the code and data.

Can you refer me some relevant documents?

Thanks

Comment: Javascript, HTML, and CSS can't really be secured because the browser needs to be able to read them as plain text. There are ways to run them through an obfuscater, but I have no experience with that so I don't know how reliable it is.

Comment: just found out that the famous Chrome Shortcut is just for Live Applications hosted on servers

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider making a Chrome plugin instead.  As rcapote already mentioned, you can't really make JS secure in the way you want (even with an obfuscator).  However, IF you can lock down your environment sufficiently, a Chrome plunging will be a lot more secure.

To be really safe though, as much as I hate to say it, you should really switch to a compiled format instead.  There are even JS compilers (that compile to other languages).